# How to construct a SQL sub query in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

I have requirement to extract total number of rows from a table - `ci_periodicBillings` only for clients where they have rows from a particular date range from another table - `ci_invoiceHeaders`. I am using MS SQL Server 2008, connecting via ODBC.

I have created a subquery which works but only if the total number of rows from ci_periodicBillings is 1. I'm finding if there is more than 1 result from ci_periodicBillings, it's multiplying the rows found by the number of rows meeting the criteria from ci_invoiceHeaders.

I only want to show only the rows from ci_periodicBillings without any multiplication if the criteria is met in ci_invoiceHeaders. I'm sure there is an easy solution to this but I can't see the wood from the trees at the moment.

There are a few other tables used for listing purposes only (i.e. facilities/clients etc)

SQL is here:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

SELECT     


     b.name,
      b.forename, 
      b.surname,


       a.client,
       cast(a.BILLSTART as DATE) as BILLSTART, 
       cast(a.ENDBILL as DATE) as ENDBILL,
       a.RATE



           FROM         ci_periodicBillings as a
           inner join 
           (select f.name,     
           c.surname,c.forename,ih.client,ih.invoiceDate      
           FROM ci_invoiceHeaders ih
           LEFT JOIN ci_invoiceDetails id ON ih.invoiceNo = id.id
           INNER JOIn cs_clients c ON ih.client = c.guid
           INNER JOIN cs_facilities f ON c.facility = f.guid
           group by f.name, c.surname, 
           c.forename, ih.client,     ih.invoiceDate)   
           as b
           on  a.client = b.client 
    WHERE b.invoiceDate between '2017-08-01' and '2018-01-31'
    order by a.client
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Take a few minutes and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: If you have multiple rates or start / end dates in `ci_periodicBillings`, which one do you want to show? hint: `group by` and `max`

Comment: If you provide the sample data and expected output then it would helpful to understand question easily

Comment: It seems that "LEFT JOIN ci_invoiceDetails id ON ih.invoiceNo = id.id" is not required as you are not using it further.... try to remove this and check

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2008 connecting via ODBC to a hosted relational database.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  b.name, b.forename, b.surname, a.client,
       cast(a.BILLSTART AS DATE) AS BILLSTART, 
       cast(a.ENDBILL AS DATE) AS ENDBILL, a.RATE
FROM ci_periodicBillings AS a inner join 
           (SELECT f.name, c.surname,c.forename,ih.client,DATE(ih.invoiceDate) invoiceDate    
           FROM ci_invoiceHeaders ih
           LEFT JOIN ci_invoiceDetails id ON ih.invoiceNo = id.id
           INNER JOIn cs_clients c ON ih.client = c.guid
           INNER JOIN cs_facilities f ON c.facility = f.guid
           WHERE ih.invoiceDate BETWEEN '2017-08-01' AND '2018-01-31'
           GROUP BY f.name, c.surname,c.forename,ih.client,DATE(ih.invoiceDate)) AS b
ON a.client = b.client 
ORDER BY a.client;
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work. I don't want to make distinct from ci_invoiceHeaders but distinct on the rows returned by ci_periodicBillings but distinct doesn't work on those.